# Cannot access sklearn module

Tags: python, scikit-learn, module

I successfully installed scikit-learn:

```
Requirement already satisfied: `scikit-learn` in c:\users\agust\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.3.0)
```

But I'm getting the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn' when trying to import sklearn.
```

I'm in a `conda` environment (3.9.17): anaconda3\envs\tensor\python.exe.

If I print the `sys.path` I get the following:

```
['c:\\Users\\agust\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\Pruebas Python\\tensor',
 'C:\\Users\\agust\\anaconda3\\envs\\tensor\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\agust\\anaconda3\\envs\\tensor\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\agust\\anaconda3\\envs\\tensor\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\agust\\anaconda3\\envs\\tensor',
 'C:\\Users\\agust\\anaconda3\\envs\\tensor\\lib\\site-packages']
```

What should I do in order for this environment to be able to import sklearn?

I am using vscode

I have tried updating conda and other stuff but keep getting this error. numpy and pandas are working just fine.

Comment: Were you in the conda environment when you originally installed scikit?